# InstallShield 2015 setup and update env path on Windows 10

Tags: installshield

I’m using InstallShield 2015 SP1 with Basic MSI project

When installing my setup on Windows 10 machine, it seems that restart or logoff is needed for the path environment variable to be updated.

The path is updated with the .ism file under Environment Variables,
I tried using custom action that run this InstallScript code ( taken from InstallShield help ) to avoid restart but it didn’t helped, Any ideas ?

```
#define WM_WININICHANGE 0x001A
#define HWND_BROADCAST 0xffff
STRING szKey, szEnv;
WPOINTER pEnv;

begin
    // Flush the registry to all applications.
    szEnv = "Environment";
    pEnv = &szEnv;
    SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, pEnv );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to put the CA after InstallFinalize.